# Is there an accurate "World History Timeline" for all geographic areas?

Tags: world, timeline

Many years ago I had in my possession a large poster of a timeline that attempted to depict the main events attached to all the cultures known to have existed.

I think I found it in a Japanese museum (it contained captions both in English and Japanese), but nowadays I cannot remember which one exactly that could have been.

After moving between different places over the last years/decades I lost the poster, and recently tried to find a similar timeline document.
Unfortunately so far I only found extremely Euro-centered versions of the poster, that do not represent accurately the history of other regions.

Is there a good "World History Timeline" providing a similar level of details for all geographic areas?

Comment: There's one that I see often in used book sales. Maybe someone else remembers its name. Its a large softback and the most common edition is a burgundy red color.

Comment: We have rejected this question before - as you point out, "accurate" is subjective.  One timeline will be Euro-centric, another will be from the perspective of a Marxist, a third will be Creationist. All will insist that they are "accurate" - there is no objective standard against which to compare them.  And a month later someone will release a new timeline and the answer will be invalid.

Answer (score 2):

While looking up a map for a recent question I ran into [Timemaps](https://www.timemaps.com/history/), which you might find interesting. It's interactive rather than a poster, and allows to zoom in and out of regions and countries, browse timelines forward and back, and read some details about what's going on. [Example](https://www.timemaps.com/history/east-asia-200bc/).

They're a commercial venture run by historians, and seem to target the teachers' market. They don't seem to offer any posters, but like any business they'll be on the lookout for potential sources of revenue that they haven't thought about. You might get lucky if you [ask them](https://www.timemaps.com/contact-us/) to make one. (It seems, to me, that this ought to be a no brainer yes decision.)

Alternatively, googling "world history timeline" reveals a few existing options. [Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0721709419).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this timeline? I have a large collection of history timelines. I have **4 Japanese world history timelines** in the collection.

[image]

Comment: In my memories the poster also had captions in English but this looks very close, thanks a lot for bringing it back James. Do you remember where you found those?

Comment: Very interesting that you have such a collection, do you digitalize it?

Comment: Yes, I have it both digital and books and charts. Please, contact me by mail. I have another Japanese histomap that has both English and Japanese editions that might interest you. It's a file type I cannot post here.